# Forward declarations cause errors after code refactor

Tags: c++, namespaces, refactoring, forward-declaration, using-directives

My original class structure was similar to:

```
//def.h
namespace A
{
   struct X {};
}
```

and forward declarations where needed:

```
//file that needs forward declarations
namespace A { struct X; }
```

After some refactoring, `X` was moved to a different namespace, but to keep old code "working" `using` directives were used:

```
//def.h
namespace B
{
   struct X {};
}
namespace A
{
   using ::B::X;
}
```

Now we can access the same class keeping the old syntax `A::X`, but the forward declarations cause errors. The second problem is that the error message I'm getting doesn't point to where the forward declarations are, and finding/replacing the forward declarations is time-consuming.

For now I fixed the problem (the hard way).

What is the best approach to deal with this situation?

IMO, the `using` shouldn't be there at all, and all code that uses `X` should be refactored to accomodate the new namespace (this is one solution), but unfortunately this isn't an option.

The actual code is a lot more complicated, this is a simplified example.

Comment: I'm guessing `fwd.h` is not `def_fwd.h`, that is, a header whose entire intent is to forward declare some other header names?

Comment: @K-ballo it's just a name, the forward-declarations are per-implementation file.

Comment: Well, that gives away my suggestion to deal with this. Taken from the _Standard Library_ (see `iosfwd`), _Boost_ (all over the place), et. al.

Comment: Was `X` moved to an existing namespace `B` or was `namespace A` renamed to `B`? In the latter case, could you possibly use namespace aliases?

Comment: @rhalbersma existing namespace - `A` still exists.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore What are your error messages?

Comment: @rhalbersma http://ideone.com/CxhctQ

Comment: @LuchianGrigore you are mixing "direct" forward declarations and "indirect" ones through the using declarations. converting all forward declarations to the latter form in a single fwd header should help.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I update my answer with a Standard quote about namespace member lookup rules.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is more about new code than about refactoring existing code, but I like using a special header called `X_fwd.hpp` for such cases.

```
// X_def.hpp
namespace B
{
   struct X {};
}
namespace A
{
   // NOT: using namespace B; // does not participate in ADL!      
   typedef ::B::X X;  // OR: using ::B::X;
}

// X_fwd.hpp
namespace A { struct X; }

// some file needing declaration of X
#include <X_fwd.hpp>
```

This makes it a lot easier to find forward declarations, and also to change them after the fact, because the change is isolated in one place only (DRY...).

**NOTE1**: AFAIK, there is no technical difference between using Peter Wood's answer of a `typedef` and your `using` declaration. Note that a `using` directive `using namespace B;` could cause trouble because these are ignored by **Argument-Dependent-Lookup**. Even worse, some of your code might then even **silently call the wrong function overload** because you are not pulling in the new namespace `B` anymore!

**NOTE2**: In the comments to the question, an [Ideone](http://ideone.com/CxhctQ) example was given. This nicely illustrates a subtlety about name lookup inside namespaces: to quote from the draft [Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf), section **3.4.3.2 Namespace members [namespace.qual]**, clause 2

> For a namespace X and name m, the namespace-qualiﬁed lookup set S(X,
>   m) is deﬁned as follows: Let S'(X, m) be the set of all declarations
>   of m in X and the inline namespace set of X (7.3.1). If S'(X, m) is
>   not empty, S(X, m) is S'(X, m); otherwise, S(X, m) is the union of
>   S(Ni, m) for all namespaces Ni nominated by using-directives in X and
>   its inline namespace set.

This explains the following tricky ambiguity

```
namespace A
{
    struct X1{};
    struct X2{};
}

namespace B
{
    using A::X1;    // OK: lookup-set is both namespace A and B, and a single unique name is found (at this point!)
    struct X1;      // OK: lookup-set is namespace B, and a single unique name is found

    struct X2;      // OK: lookup-set is namespace B, and a single unique name is found
    using A::X2;    // error: lookup-set is both namespace A and B, and no unique name is found (at this point!)
}
```

So the validity of having both a direct declaration and a using-declaration with the same name inside a namespace is order-dependent. Hence the convenience of a single declaration in a fwd header file.

Comment: It's still an error to have a struct declaration and a typedef share a name. And typedefs don't affect ADL either.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Tnx, updated to reflect subtle difference between using directive and typedef/using declaration.

Comment: +1 for the last subtlety - I saw this when fixing the issue myself but couldn't explain why.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I had quite a bit of fun finding the precise details. The Standard starts out quite hilariously in section 3.4: "The name lookup rules apply uniformly to all names [...]" and then followed by 14(!) pages of unqualified, qualified, using directives, using declarations and other intricate details ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to fix the code.

You can do it in two steps :

1. fix all forward declares
2. remove `using ::B::X;`

Comment: Yes, I thought so too, and this is what I did (without removing the `using` directives, that's not an option).