# No warning on deleting a forward declared pointer (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, memory-leaks, forward-declaration

Deleting forward declared pointers leads to undefined behavior.

Examples:

- https://gist.github.com/jatinganhotra/4144778
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382111/399908

However, my Visual Studio (VS2012) compiler doesn't warn me about it.

- Is this an unfixed [VS2012 compiler bug](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/08/10/10338661.aspx)?
- Did I disable ([or never enable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23k5d385.aspx)) the corresponding warning?
- Is this specific to some project setting?
- Visual Leak Detector hinted me to the problem, but is there some method (pragma, code, macro, ...) to detect this at compile time?

Comment: The respective warning is [C4150](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba5dy3f2(v=vs.110).aspx). It is warning level 2 and should be active by default.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: My warning level was too low. Why not add your comment as an answer so I can accept it...

Comment: Add a comment to the answer if you want to comment on it or add something but do not edit.

Comment: @Pixelchemist You're right, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The respective warning is [`C4150`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba5dy3f2(v=vs.110).aspx).

It should be active by default and it is categorized in warning level 2 (which should be active too, since default warning level is `W3` afaik).

Note: Instead of lowering the warning level, try to pragma warnings in specific cases.

Comment: One can give a new warning level to a single warning via compiler flag `/wnxxxx` where n is the new level and xxxx the code of the warning. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4152419/399908).